# How do I decorate a partially applied function in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, functional-programming

I created a decorator factory that is parameterized by a custom logging function like so:

```
def _log_error(logger):
    def decorator(f):
        @wraps(f)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            try:
                return f(*args, **kwargs)
            except Exception as e:
                logger(e)
                return None
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

Which I now want to use to decorate a partially-applied function foo:

```
foo = partial(bar, someparam)
```

I've tried all of the following:

```
@_log_error(logger)
foo = partial(bar, someparam)

log_error = _log_error(logger)
@log_error
foo = partial(...)

foo = partial(...)
@log_error
foo

@log_error
(foo = partial(...))
```

AFAICT both `log_error = _log_error(logger) / @log_error` and `@_log_error(logger)` seem totally valid ways of producing the decorator and it works fine on normally declared functions. But when trying to use on the partially applied function I get syntax errors at the start of `foo =`, and googling while yielding excellent resources on working with decorators and `functools.partial` in general have not given me anything on this specific case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Decorators don't work on assignments. But since using a decorator is the same thing as calling the decorator, you can do

```
foo = _log_error(logger)(partial(bar, someparam))
```

Answer (score 3):

**Either way works**

Here's another way you can do it using `Either` – This answer gets its inspiration from Brian Lonsdorf's egghead series: [*Professor Frisby Introduces Composable Functional JavaScript*](https://egghead.io/courses/professor-frisby-introduces-composable-functional-javascript)

We'll take some of what we learned there and write some super sweet functional python codes

```
class Map (dict):
  def __init__(self, **xw):
    super(Map, self).__init__(**xw)
    self.__dict__ = self

def Left (x):
  return Map(
    fold = lambda f, g: f(x),
    bimap = lambda f, g: Left(f(x))
  )

def Right (x):
  return Map(
    fold = lambda f, g: g(x),
    bimap = lambda f, g: Right(g(x))
  )
```

> **Note:** This is a *very* incomplete implementation of `Left` and `Right` but it's enough to get this specific job done. To take advantage of the full power of this super-powered data type, you'll want a complete implementation.

---

**Generics promote code reuse**

We'll setup a few more generic functions

```
def identity (x):
  return x

def try_catch (f):
  try:
    return Right(f())
  except Exception as e:
    return Left(e)

def partial (f, *xs, **xw):
  def aux (*ys, **yw):
    return f(*xs, *ys, **xw, **yw)
  return aux
```

Now we have enough to define `log_error` – the syntax is a little wonky for writing curried functions in Python, but everything works as expected.

In plain English: we `try` applying `f` and get back a value. If the value is an error (`Left`), call `logger`, otherwise return the value (`identity`)

```
def log_error (logger):
  def wrapper (f):
    def aux (*xs, **xw):
      return try_catch (lambda: f(*xs, **xw)).bimap(logger, identity)
    return aux
  return wrapper
```

---

**Putting it all together**

Now let's try it with a little function

```
def foo (x,y,z):
  return (x + y) * z
```

What you wanted to do was wrap a partially applied function in your using your custom logger

```
foo_logger = log_error(lambda err: print("ERROR:" + str(err))) (partial(foo,'a'))

foo_logger('b',3).fold(print, print)
# ('a' + 'b') * 3
# 'ab' * 3
# => ababab

foo_logger(1,3).fold(print, print)
# ('a' + 1) * 3
# ERROR: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly
# => None
```

---

**Understanding the results**

As you can see, when there is no error present (`Right`), evaluation just keeps on moving and the computed value is passed to `print`.

When an error occurs (`Left`), the logger picks it up and logs the error message to the console. Because the logging function has no return value, `None` is passed along to `print`

Comment: Monads in Python! Well-played.